# JEST test on node and typescript returns: TypeError: is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to run a simple function test with JEST on the Node running Typescript.
I am getting not a function error and I don't understand why.

test.spec.js:

```
const x = require('../functions/x');

describe("Running test", () => {
  test('Should return results', async() => {
    const result = x(1,2)
    expect(result).toBe(3)
  });
});
```

x.ts:

```
export function x(a: number, b: number) {
  return a + b
}
```

result:

```
  Running test
    ✕ Should return results (2 ms)

  ● Running test › Should return results

    TypeError: x is not a function

      4 | describe("Running test", () => {
      5 |   test('Should return results', async() => {
    > 6 |     const result = x(1,2)
        |                    ^
      7 |     expect(result).toBe(3)
      8 |     /*
      9 |     const result = await brokerStatsMessagesCount()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running your project with typescript, your test files should be in `.ts` too (maybe you'll need to adjust jest config to make it run properly).

Try to export the x function this way in `x.ts`:

```js
export const x = (a: number, b: number) => {
  return a + b
}
```

Change `test.spec.js` to `test.spec.ts` and import `x` this way:

```js
import { x } from '../functions/x'
```

Comment: Thank you so much I have already resolved this. But thank you for the answer. This is the correct answer. Maybe it will help someone down the line.